# How to get a dynamically generated element in Angular without querySelector?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-universal

**I am currently creating my own toastr service as seen in the GIF below**

---

[image]

---

**What I want to achieve**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tgm4st?file=src/app/app.component.ts
*But without queryselector. From what i have read, you should not be using queryselector for retrieving elements in the DOM in angular*

---

**The issue**
Whenever I click the CTA button I add a toast element to an array of toasts which the component is subscribed to and utilizes to update the DOM.

The toasts are generated like this:

```
export class ToastComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private toast: ToastService, protected elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  toasts = this.toast.Toasts;
```

---

```
  <div
    class="toast-wrapper wobble-animation"
    *ngFor="let t of toasts.value"
    (click)="DestroyToast(t, $event)"
```

---

**What I want**
I want to add an eventlistener to the toast whenever 'animationend' to destroy the HTML element. I already do this by when clicking with this line of code:

```
       DestroyToast(element, event): void {
        event.target.classList.remove('wobble-animation');
        event.target.classList.add('slide-out-animation');
        event.target.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
          this.toasts.value.splice(this.toasts.value.indexOf(element), 1);
        });
      }
```

My initial thought was to subscribe to the array and use that as an eventlistener for when something is pushed. I would then use a function to fetch the latest toast and add another eventlistener, the 'animationend' one.

I tried the method like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.toast.Toasts.subscribe((args) => {
      this.UpdateToasts();
     });
  }
  UpdateToasts() {
    let toastElements = document.querySelectorAll('.toast');
    console.log(toastElements);
  }
```

But unfortunately it is too slow and always returns null on the first event.

[image]

---

I think that I have read that using querySelector in angular is generally bad practice. So the question is:

## How to get a dynamically generated element in Angular without querySelector?

---

#### FULL CODE

**Toast.Component.ts**

```
import { ToastService } from './../../services/toast.service';
import { toast } from './toast.model';
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toast',
  templateUrl: './toast.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toast.component.scss'],
})
export class ToastComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private toast: ToastService, protected elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  toasts = this.toast.Toasts;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.toast.Toasts.subscribe((args) => {
      this.UpdateToasts();
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.toasts.unsubscribe();
  }
  DestroyToast(element, event): void {
    event.target.classList.remove('wobble-animation');
    event.target.classList.add('slide-out-animation');
    event.target.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
      this.toasts.value.splice(this.toasts.value.indexOf(element), 1);
    });
  }
  UpdateToasts() {
    let toastElements = document.querySelectorAll('.toast');
    console.log(toastElements);
  }
}
```

**Toast.Component.html**

```
<div class="toast-container">
  <div
    class="toast-wrapper wobble-animation"
    *ngFor="let t of toasts.value"
    (click)="DestroyToast(t, $event)"
  >
    <div
      class="toast default"
      [ngClass]="{ 'slide-out-animation': t.TimeLeft < 1 }"
    >
      <div class="notification-count" *ngIf="t.Count > 1">
        {{ t.Count }}
      </div>
      <div class="content-container">
        <p class="title">
          {{ t.Title }}
        </p>
        <p class="content">{{ t.Content }}</p>
      </div>
      <span class="progress">
        <span
          class="real-progress"
          [ngStyle]="{ 'width.%': t.PercentageCompleted }"
        ></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Toast.Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject';
import { toast } from '../components/toast/toast.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ToastService {
  public Toasts = new BehaviorSubject<Array<object>>([]);

  constructor() {}

  Toast(Title: string, Message?: string, Style?: string, Timer?: number) {
    const toastModel = new toast({
      Title: Title,
      Content: Message,
      Timer: Timer,
      Style: Style,
      TimeLeft: Timer,
      Count: 1,
      PercentageCompleted: 100,
    });
    this.AddToast(toastModel);
  }

  private AddToast(toast: toast) {
    const currentArr = this.Toasts.value;
    const updatedToast = [...currentArr, toast];
    let timer = setInterval(function () {
      toast.PercentageCompleted = toast.TimeLeft / (toast.Timer / 100);
      toast.TimeLeft = toast.TimeLeft - 10;
      if (toast.TimeLeft <= 0 || !toast.TimeLeft) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 10);
    this.Toasts.next(updatedToast);
  }
}
```

Link to website with live code [ModernnaMedia](https://ModernaMedia.no)

Comment: Please add a minimal code [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) example showing your use case so it's easier for everyone to provide a solution, btw. [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) should be enough to solve your issue, you just need to move your logic to `ngOnChanges` to prevent null references

Comment: @LuisLimas Thanks! I will look into it when i get off work. I'll let you know how it goes :)

Comment: @LuisLimas I have updated and added stackbiz!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understood you correctly, there seem to be two `animationend` events going on.

> I want to add an eventlistener to the toast whenever 'animationend' to destroy the HTML element.

You can bind that directly in the template:

```html
<div
  *ngFor="let toast of toasts"
  #toastEl
  (animationend)="DestroyToast(toastEl)"
  class="toast">
</div>
```

```js
DestroyToast(toastEl: HTMLElement) {
    // …
}
```

Comment: Wow did not know you could do tthat! Thats great but unfortunately I have 2 animations. one entry and one exit. I can solve this issue if I am able to use document.querySelector(); but as mentioned, the query selector returns null. This can be solved with a timeout, but I want to try and stick to angular best principles. However, your answer could be a backup solution. +1

Comment: Angular also has its own animation framework that might be worth looking into (opinions on it differ – it's also fine to stick with CSS animations, but the animation framework does give you some integration options).

Comment: I see, thanks for the tip! I have been looking into it, but I prefer CSS animations

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned by others already, using `ViewChildren` would be the "Angular" way to do it, instead of queryselector. We can also with `ViewChildren` subscribe to changes of the querylist we are listening to! I think that is probably suitable for your code...

So first, attach a ref to the toasts, here I just call it `myToasts`:

```
<div
  #myToasts
  class="toast default"
  [ngClass]="{ 'slide-out-animation': t.TimeLeft < 1 }"
>
```

OK, now declare the querylist in the component:

```
@ViewChildren('myToasts') myToasts: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Now you can simply subscribe to the changes in `AfterViewInit` and do whatever you need to do with the elements:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myToasts.changes.subscribe(toasts => {
    console.log('Array length: ', toasts.length);
    console.log('Array of elements: ', toasts.toArray())
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this looks very promising. I will test it and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

if you add rxjs delay function after your observable variable like below

```
this.toast.Toasts.pipe(delay(0)).subscribe(()=>{this.UpdateToasts();})
```

you will not get null reference error.
and if you don't want to use queryselector you can use angular viewchildren
for more information visit angular documentation site.
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Comment: You could also use SetTimeout, however i strongly believe that this is not best practice. However thanks for your suggestion